# Unable to get the right type in cellForItemAtIndexPath in my UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my `UICollectionView`, in its `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, I am trying to typecast the cell to my custom cell of type `MyCollectionViewCell`. But the object is still resolved as just a `UICollectionViewCell`. What could be the issue? I have associated the cell with my custom class that inherits from `UICollectionViewCell` in my storyboard. Please see the images below.

[image: The cell is correctly assigned to my custom UICollectionViewCell class]

[image: Reuse identifier is set correctly too]

[image: My cell is not getting resolved to the expected type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `viewDidLoad` method, replacing

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

with

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

fixed the issue.

Commenting that entire line also seemed to work.

Comment: It is also working without the line of code because the storyboard automatically registers your custom cell to your collectionView using the identifier you provide in the inspector. You only need to register your cell manually when you are not using storyboards.